# Data Alerts only in SharePoint?

Tags: reporting-services, alert

I have a quick question for those of you who have happened to work with Data Alerts.

Are they only available on SharePoint ? could that be ?

because i have been trying to configure them on the Report Server, but there seems to be no Option available for them.

Thanks a lot in Advance

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492252.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data alerts are only available in SharePoint mode, according to [this feature matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157231.aspx#bkmk_featuresupport). This question has been asked and answered on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/22fb12c9-a61a-4650-bd98-22b00f372be6/data-alerts-in-ssrs-native-mode-alternatives?forum=sqlreportingservices). The answer notes that a workaround could be to create a [data-driven subscription](http://bisherryli.com/2011/08/13/ssrs-60-steps-to-implement-a-data-driven-subscription/).